# How to permanently add options to a select HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select menu and a means to add options to that select menu (through user input) and I'm saving that new option in a database.  However, when I navigate to a different page, the option disappears when I come back.  Is there any way to permanently add it to the HTML?

The code to add user input to the list:

```
function addItem(){
    var item = document.getElementById('item');
    var itemList = document.getElementById('itemList');
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = item.value;
    var autosel = option.value;
    option.text = item.value;
    var addOption = itemList.options.add(option)
    new Option(addOption);
    $("#items").val(autosel).trigger('change');


}
```

This is working fine to add the item to the list and then autoselect it, but it's keeping it there that I'm having an issue with.  The HTML is below:

```
<select name="items" id="items" class = "itemsel">
                        <option value="opt1">Opt1</option>
                        <option value="opt2">Opt2</option>
                        <input type="text" name="item" id="item" />
                        <input type="button" class = "gold" value="Add to List" onclick="addItem()"/><br/>
</select>
```

I'm thinking it might be something to do with creating an actual `<option>` within the HTML, but I'm not sure on how I could do this.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're saving it in the database, you'll need to load it from the database every time the page is loaded.

Comment: You have improper HTML, you cannot have inputs / buttons inside a select.

Comment: You need to read the options out of the database on page load. You are currently only saving the information to the database.

Comment: Why are you mixing native JS with jQuery?

Comment: @Terry I was under the impression that this was OK?  Since I'm not 100% comfortable with JQuery, I have only used it where helpful for me.  Will it negatively impact the code?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what your shared, which doesn't include your server-side code at all. You are only manipulating the DOM within that page, which will not persist at all.

What you are doing is a great start for a quickly responding page, but now you need to have that information also push to your server. Once you have values added into your persistent storage, you can retrieve them and use them to populate the HTML at render time (or load them via AJAX at DOM Ready time).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to save the options in the database (which you can do using AJAX/XHR), you can use javascript localstorage.
It has its pros and cons.

Pros:
 - Don't need database nor API calls
 - Everything is local, so you don't have transmissions delays when saving or loading

Cons:
 - It's local, so if the user changes the browser or delete the local data, the option will be lost.

You just have to think about your needs and choose the option it's best for you ;)

Then, that options needs to be loaded everytime the page is loaded (and that's the point of using local storage), and applied again to the HTML elements.

Comment: Thanks for the information, could I use LocalStorage for some things and SQLite for others? Or would this be bad practice?

Comment: It will depend on your needs. For example, In my work we are developing a quite big application which, for a specific part uses both. General company customization options for that part are stored in the database but each user can customize that part according to their preferences, and that is stored in javascript. Of course, if an user clean its history or change browser the preferences will be lost, but it/s not very important information so it's ok ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that the development required to maintian a web application is different than the development required to develop a generic web page.

A web application will have a front end portion (the html stuff) and a back end portion (often called the server side stuff).  Unless you are using the HTML5 local store, your datase stuff should be handled by the back end portion of the web application.

To tie this into your question, you will need to do something like this:

1. When the page loads, the back end will need to store the "customer configured options" in something that is accessible to the page, the request seems like a good choice for this if the options apply to only the current page.  If the options apply to multiple pages, consider storing the information in the session.
2. When the client (page user) adds an option to the select item, the front end stuff (javascript, in your case) will need to send the new option information to the back end.  AJAX is a common (and, in my opinion, good) way to accomplish this.
3. The back end will store the new option information in a data store (also known as database).  Seems like SQLLite is your database.

You will need to understand the difference between when and where the page is rendered (on the server) and when and where the javascript on the page runs (in the client browser).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was able to retrieve the user inputted values from SQLite and then populate the select list on page load :)